# How do I make a play command in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to know how to make a play command. I got it to join the Voice Channel, but it will not play any music.

Here's the code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!play")) {
        const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

        message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
            const stream = ytdl(args[1], { filter: "audioonly" });
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

            dispatcher.on("finish", () => voiceChannel.leave());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [discord-ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-ytdl-core) instead of ytdl-core and try the below code

```
    client.on("message", (message) => {
        if (message.content.startsWith("!play")) {
           const ytdl = require("discord-ytdl-core");
            const args = message.content.trim().split(' ');
            message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
                const stream = ytdl(args[1], { filter: "audioonly",opusEncoded: true });
                const dispatcher = connection.play(stream, { type: "opus" }).on("finish", () => connection.disconnect());
            });
        }
    });
```

Edit: also make sure you have ffmpeg and opusscript installed

Comment: Did not work. just connected but didnt play anything.

Comment: What OS are you on? Do you have ffmpeg and opusscript installed?

Comment: Sadly, I use chromebook, so I use [repl.it](https://replit.com) IDE. and i dont know

Comment: go to repl.it's shell and install ffmpeg-static and opusscript using `npm i ffmpeg-static opusscript`

Comment: I tried to replicate your bot in repl.it and made it work. I am dropping the [link](https://replit.com/@binoy638/discord-bot-test#index.js) here in case you wanna check.